# How to resolve an dependency not found vue?

Tags: vuejs3

I installed vue 3, but when i run npm run dev, i get an error. I don't know how to resolve it :

This dependency was not found:

- vue in ./node_modules/@websanova/vue-auth/src/v3.js, ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js and 7 others

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly by "I installed vue 3" - but I guess you mean that you updated to Vue 3 from Vue 2.x in your existing project because neither `@websanova/vue-auth` nor `bootstrap-vue` is part of Vue 3

The error you see is very probably caused by the fact `bootstrap-vue` (current release v2.21.2.) **is not compatible with Vue 3 and requires Vue 2.x** ([v2.6 is required, v2.6.12 is recommended](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs)) - support for Vue 3 is [still in development](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196) and currently there is no even alpha/beta release available for Vue 3

Stay with Vue 2 for now and monitor the issue linked for updates....

Comment: Tank you for your answer. Yes i dit it, i updated vue. Sorry i explained bad. Okay thank you, i wil do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try delete your folder of node_modules and re install with
`npm install`

Comment: I tried already and before to install, i clean the cache folder. And i get this error

Comment: try: npm install @websanova/vue-auth
[vue-auth](https://websanova.com/docs/vue-auth/guides/startup)

Comment: thank you for your answer i forget in the first message, no always the same  problem :/